# Adding search query to the address bar

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have seen this done before but not sure how.

I am trying to have a search form go to pagename.php?q=[searchquery] so i can then get the searchquery from the address.

here is the form

```
    <form class="sidebar-search">
    <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Quick Product Search..." />                
    <input type="button" class="submit" value="" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the JS

```
// handle the search query submit on enter press
        $('.sidebar-search input').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                window.location.href = "search_results.php";
                return false; //<---- Add this line
            }
        });

        // handle the search submit
        $('.sidebar-search .submit').click(function () {
            if ($('.page-container').hasClass("sidebar-closed")) {
                if ($('.sidebar-search').hasClass('open') == false) {
                    $('.sidebar-search').addClass("open");
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "search_results.php";
                }
            } else {
                window.location.href = "search_results.php";
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
window.location.href = "search_results.php?q=" + $(".sidebar-search input[type=text]").val();
```

Or you can give an id to the search and get the value of the element with that ID.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't actually need to do it using javascript

```
<form class="sidebar-search" method="get" action="search_results.php">
    <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Quick Product Search..." />                
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The `action` attibute defines the location (an URL) where the form's collected data should be sent.
The `method` attribute defines which HTTP method to send the data with (it can be "get" or "post").

This would probably help understand in detail.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FForms%2FMy_first_HTML_form

But if you still need to use javascript here the answer
define an `id` for the search field as below

```
    <input type="text"  id="txtSearch" placeholder="Quick Product Search..." />
```

and then

```
var searchString = $('#txtSearch').val();
window.location.href = "search_results.php?q=" + searchString;
```

Comment: Thanks i have changed my code to `<div class="row-fluid search-forms search-default">
         <form class="form-search" method="get" action="search_results.php">
          <div class="chat-form">
           <div class="input-cont">   
                       <input type="text"  placeholder="Search..." class="m-wrap" />
           </div>
           <button type="button" class="btn green">Search &nbsp; <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
          </div>
         </form>
        </div>` 
and this still doesnt work?

Comment: You need to have the type attribute of the button as `submit` not `button` `<button type="submit class="btn green">`

Answer (score 0):

if you hit enter/submit you go to search.php?query=value

```
<form method="get" action="search.php" >
    <input name="query" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```